# Atmel studio with Xmega Timer/USART

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmelstudio

I'm new in embedded systems developing also in Atmel studio Environment,
I'm using Atxmega128a1 with 32MHz system clk.
I'm trying to send some characters to the PC thought RS232 module at every timer interrupt overflow (0.05s),
so I defined (tc)Timers,USART Drivers on ASF and wrote the below code in main.c file, finally  I debugged it without any error but not succeeded to transmit any thing through serial port.
 anyone can help me or give me some advices.

```
    #include <asf.h>

    volatile int flag=0;
    uint8_t received_byte;
    uint8_t tx_buf[] = "\n\rHello AVR world ! : ";
    uint8_t tx_length = 22;
    uint8_t i;

    static void my_callback(void)
     {

         flag =1;
     }

   int main (void)
    {
/* Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()). */

    board_init();
    sysclk_init();
    static usart_rs232_options_t USART_SERIAL_OPTIONS = {
          .baudrate = 9600,
          .charlength = 8,
          .paritytype = USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc,
          .stopbits = false
    };
  usart_init_rs232(& USARTF0, &USART_SERIAL_OPTIONS);


//usart_set_baudrate_precalculated(& USARTF0,0x00017700,0x01E84800);

/* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */
   if (flag==1)
    {

    //received_byte = usart_getchar(& USARTF0);
    //if (received_byte == '\r') {
            for (i = 0; i < tx_length; i++)
             {
            usart_putchar(& USARTF0, tx_buf[i]);
             }
     } 
      else
       usart_putchar(& USARTF0, received_byte);
            flag=0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the initialization of the related system clock module:

```
sysclk_enable_module(SYSCLK_PORT_F, PR_USART0_bm);
```

Comment: thank you Rev1 the problem was in definning the TX pin on port F  as output:
                 PORTF.DIRSET = PIN3_bm;